# Как верстать макеты из монтажной области Photoshop?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Доброго времени суток, господа.

Одно время занимался версткой сайтов, забросил, не следил за развитием технологий.

Прислали тут один .psd файл, в котором куча монтажных областей. Что-то новое для меня. Выделил монтажную область в отдельный документ. Дальше вошёл в ступор - а с размерами что? Размер области 2500x6000px. И тут возникает затык.

Если я правильно понял, это рисовалось в Sketch. Но тем не менее, мне прислали файл .psd с монтажными областями, и я задаюсь вопросом - как это верстать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать редактор brackets,  у него есть плагин extract, как раз для работы с psd макетами. Очень удобно.